# rlocus() - Not enough input arguments in MATLAB 2018a

Tags: matlab

I am following [this tutorial](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?aux=Extras_PZ) on root locus methods and when writing:

```
syms s
sys = 1/(3*s^2 + 2*s - 1);
rlocus(sys)
```

I get:

> Error using rlocus
>   Not enough input arguments.

Why is `rlocus` expecting more input arguments when the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/rlocus.html) states that one input argument is enough?

---

> rlocus(SYS) computes and plots the root locus of the single-input,
>       single-output LTI model SYS. The root locus plot is used to analyze 
>       the negative feedback loop

Syntax for `rlocus`:

```
rlocus(sys)
rlocus(sys1,sys2,...)
[r,k] = rlocus(sys)
r = rlocus(sys,k)
```

Comment: Did you re-define the function? Type `which rlocus` and see if the result is a function within the MATLAB toolbox.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No I did not re-define the function - `...Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\toolbox\control\ctrlobsolete\rlocus.m`. Strangely it is in the `obsolete` folder.

Comment: Strange indeed. Does `which rlocus(sys)` return the same thing?

Comment: The documentation link is likely a method of a transfer function object. It may not support symbolic functions. Your call might have reached the obsolete rlocus function which might have operated differently and expects more inputs.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, yes it does.

Comment: @Navan, could very well be, so does it mean that the tutorial code is wrong? I have been following code and examples from that website for quite some time now and rarely (if ever) have I found mistakes.

Comment: I do not see `syms` used in the tutorial. It uses `tf` to create transfer function which should work fine.

Comment: @Navan, unfortunately it does not. That gives an error, that's why it is already corrected in my code. The name "s" does not match any channel or group.

Comment: All the code in that tutorial runs fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Does `wchich rlocus` yield the same return as presented above?

Comment: yes. it gives same path in ctrlobsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to input a transfer function to rlocus not a symbolic variable. The code you provided gave me the same error but this worked just fine

```
s=tf('s');
sys = 1/(3*s^2 + 2*s - 1);
rlocus(sys);
```